# Mesh Text vs Canvas Text performance

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and for the passed few months I only used text inside a canvas but now I've found out that I can use a Mesh Text component and render the text outside of the Canvas. What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing one of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## They solve different problems

Canvas text renders text (***very*** efficiently<sup>1</sup>) on a canvas, which exists in either screen space, camera space, or world space. Most of the time you're going to be using a screen space canvas, but the other two do exist.

TextMesh creates 3D objects that look like text in world space and its performance is not as good, nor does it look as good (IMO).

TextMesh is functionally similar to UI text on a world space canvas, however a world space canvas *must* know which **single** camera is rendering it. TextMesh exists just like all other geometry. If a world space canvas does not indicate a camera, it will use `Camera.main` and performance will suffer.

1. <sub>It is possible to set up canvases that are not performant, the key things to remember are, if the canvas asks for a camera, give it one. `Camera.main` is an uncached `GameObject.Find` call. Second, canvas objects that become dirty  (ie change) cascade their dirt upwards to the first `Canvas` in the patent hierarchy. Any canvas that is dirty treats ***all*** children as dirty. Do not dirty your entire hierarchy needlessly, it is expensive to recompute.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :)

Comment: Small amendment, since Unity 2019.4 `Camera.main` is cached internally making the overhead much smaller.